# How i can read multiple txt files?

Tags: regex, matlab

I want to get all words of my documents, but i have a problem with `file` in this code.
How do i fill `file` the fields of file with the content of the documents? This is my code:

```
textfilename=['example' '*' '.txt'];
Alltextfiles = dir(textfilename);


for i=1:length(Alltextfiles)    
    fileID (i)  = fopen(Alltextfiles(i).name,'r+');       
    file (i)  = fscanf(fileID(i), '%c',inf);         
    words (i)  = regexp(file (i), ' ', 'split');    
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `file` and `words` cell arrays.

```
for i=1:length(Alltextfiles)
    fileID(i)  = fopen(Alltextfiles(i).name,'r+');
    file{i}  = fscanf(fileID(i), '%c',inf);
    words{i}  = regexp(file{i}, ' ', 'split');
end
```

Also, consider splitting by `'\s|\n'`, I assume your regexp is not getting you the desired output.

Comment: okay, but I also have txt files that do not start with example. 
After I changed the code, I get an error. 

`text filename = ['*' '*' 'txt.'];'

Comment: Try filename = '*.txt'. If that does not work open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to read all words of a file:

```
words = textscan(fileread(fname), '%s');
```

`words` will be a N-by-1 cell array containing all the words of the file.